# Copy every 10 files from source into a target directory using cp

Tags: linux, bash, directory, command, cp

I have 110 large files inside a directory. But I cannot copy them at once since the system gets timed out after 50 min. I want to copy files 1 to 10, next 11 to 20, next 21 to 30, and so on. The order does not matter. I want to copy 10 of the files each time I write the `cp` one line command. How can I write `cp` to copy file number 11 to 20 (this is not the head or the tail)?

P.S. my laptop is macbook

The file names have blank spaces in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rsync -ai /path/to/source/directory/ /path/to/destination/directory
```

This uses `rsync` to copy all the files from the source directory to the destination directory.  If the copying is interrupted, you may restart it by simply giving the same command again.

The `-a` option (`--archive`) preserves the meta-data of the files (owner, permissions, timestamps, etc.)  This is used in subsequent runs to determine what files need to be transferred, and what files don't need to be transferred.

The `-i` option (`--itemize-changes`) causes `rsync` to output information about each transfer.

---

In [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518328/copy-every-10-files-from-source-into-a-target-directory-using-cp#comment957792_518349) you mention that you may want to do this against an AWS S3 bucket.

In that case, you may use

```
aws s3 sync /path/to/source/directory/ s3://bucket/path/to/destination/directory/
```

This would presumably also be restartable if your machine removes the connection for whatever reason.

See also

- [AWS S3 documentation about "sync"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

Note: I'm not a user of AWS, so I have no way of testing this.

Comment: Thank you very much @ Kusalananda. It works very well.

Answer (score 1):

Using *GNU* `find`, `xargs`, and `cp`, this would copy 10 files at a time:

```
d="destination_directory..."
s="source_directory..."
find "$s" -type f -print0 | xargs -0rn 10 cp -n -t "$d"
```

Comment: Thank you very much @agc. Question: let us assume I run it and it grabs 10 files to copy and it finishes copying them during the 50 min time window that the system has. Then, after I reconnect and run it again for the second time, how it would realize which 10 files have been copied to avoid?

Comment: @fary001, by using the `-n` (or `--no-clobber`) option, which prevents `cp` from overwriting an existing file.  See revised answer.

Comment: Also, it gives an error: "illegal option --r"

Comment: Thanks for the answer to my first question. Does `--n` also work for aws s3 along with `cp` command?

Comment: @fary001 Re *"gives an error"*: Odd.  The only `-r` is in `xargs -0rn ...`, so please run `xargs --version | head -1` and post the version number.

Comment: @fary001, Re *"aws s3"*:  Not sure, that would depend on various details that are best specified in the question itself rather than a comment.  (That is, if this is a question about *Amazon S3* please revise the question to make that fact clear.)  If not, there's some other networking copying util that will work.

Comment: I am not using it for aws s3 now. I will be eventually using it on aws s3 but right now just want to make sure that it works on my local computer. The error is for when the code is executed on my computer.

Comment: `xargs --version | head -1` says "illegal option -- -"

Comment: `xargs: illegal option -- -
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements]] [-J replstr]
             [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs] [-s size]
             [utility [argument ...]]`

Comment: @fary001, Thanks.  I'm running *GNU* `xargs`, but your system is not.  This is OK, the `-r` is short for `--no-run-if-empty`, which is cosmetic but not essential.  Just remove the `-r` like so:  `find "$s" -type f -print0 | xargs -0n 10 cp -n -t "$d"` and try the code again.

Comment: thank you. I ran again: now it's `-t` @agc

Comment: `cp: illegal option -- t
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
cp: illegal option -- t`

Comment: when I remove the `-t`, then nothing happens

Comment: @fary001, Although this question has a *Linux* tag, it seems those `xargs` and `cp` utils can't be the *GNU* versions that come with Linux.  Please specify what computer hardware this `cp` job is being run on, and what OS.